# Can you use $cond expression in $unwind stage?

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to execute this unwind pipeline stage:

```
{
  path: {$cond: {
    if: {$size: {'$actionBy': {$gte: 2}}},
    then: '$actionBy',
    else: '$meta'
  }},
  preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
}
```

Error displayed is: 'expected a string as the path for $unwind stage, got object' which of course is self explanatory, but is there not a way to do this?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in two steps. Something like:

```
{$set: {data:
  {$cond: {
    if: {$size: {'$actionBy': {$gte: 2}}},
    then: '$actionBy',
    else: '$meta'
  }}
}},
{$unwind: {path: '$data', preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true}}
```